# Is the C++20 Experimental Ranges in GCC 6.2 or above?

Tags: c++, gcc

I want to experiment with the C++20 experimental ranges library. I tried to search around to see whether it is implemented in GNU Compiler Collection (GCC) 6.2 or above but did not find any information. Is the range library implemented in GCC?

Comment: [This reference](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) should be helpful.

Comment: C++17 doesn't have ranges. Ranges only have a TS at this point with a subset of the range-v3 functionality (though the TS is progressing well). That said, I don't think it's implemented in any standard library yet.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude, I went through that reference as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ranges library is separate from GCC, though GCC is currently the only compiler that supports Ranges. Eric Niebler’s range-v3 library is very useful, but it is very different from the Ranges TS. The library that did implement the Ranges TS is called [cmcstl2](https://github.com/caseycarter/cmcstl2), mainly written by Casey Carter, with many contributions from Eric Niebler too. It has actually existed since 2015.

This library is header-only, and you only need to add its include directory to your include path. I define a bash alias for its quick use (you may want to do something similar):

```
alias gconcepts='g++ -fconcepts -std=c++17 -I$HOME/cmcstl2/include'
```

Comment: Great, I am going to try it https://superuser.com/a/1221885 . It seems from what you are saying that it might be better to use cmcstl2.

Comment: @alfC I did not say anything about ‘better’. Cmcstl2 implements the Ranges TS, including the concepts, which will likely be included in C++20. Range-v3 is slightly different: it implements more algorithms, has some more interesting stuff (not likely to be standardized in the near future), and does not rely on C++ concepts. I would say they serve different purposes.

Comment: Great thanks, do you know  of good material out there to learn (either) ranges library?

Comment: The range-v3 page has listed many references, which are good reads. I think he explained the rationale quite well in his blogs. The documentation https://ericniebler.github.io/range-v3/ is incomplete, but is still better than having no documentation. CMCSTL2 just implements the Ranges TS, and I do not know of other good documentation.

Answer (score 4):

I have not found any official documentation stating that GCC supports the experimental Ranges TS so far, so the answer seems to be negative.

As an additional note, Eric Niebler has a "reference" implementation for Ranges, you can find it [on github](https://github.com/ericniebler/range-v3).
The code is known to work on the following compilers:
- clang 3.6.2 (or later)
- GCC 4.9.4 (or later) (C++14 support requires GCC 5.2; C++14 "extended constexpr" support is poor before 6.1.)
- "Clang with Microsoft CodeGen" (Clang/C2) VS2015 Update 3 (or later)

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/experimental/ranges mentions hypotetical headers `<experimental/ranges/*>` but I don't know if they exists anywhere.

Comment: @alfC They have existed since 2015. See my answer.